# How do you really use dbus to obtain the list of visible SSIDs from NetworkManager?

Tags: wireless, dbus, access-point, networkmanager, nmcli

According to example 12 [here](http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.com/2012/09/dbus-tutorial-fun-with-network-manager.html) I should be able to use

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4 org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless.GetAllAccessPoints
```

to discover all available wireless access points, because `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4` is my wireless adaptor.  However, it seems to return results different from the command-line equivalent

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

which returns many more SSIDs.  Whilst experimenting with the above at work, I could only get one SSID via dbus-send.  At home, the first time I ran the `dbus-send` command it returned an array of four access points, which is the same number as returned by `nmcli`.  I ran the same `dbus-send` command again and this time it produced a list of only one access point, just as at work.

The next day at home I tried the `dbus-send` command several times and it listed just one access point.  I then ran the `nmcli` command again and it listed five access points.  After that, the `dbus-send` command also listed five access points.  It seems that the `nmcli` command somehow goes further than the `dbus-send` command to discover access points, but once it has done so, the `dbus-send` command is also able to find the access points.  That is not the case at work, however:  the `nmcli` command always discovers 12 or more APs but the `dbus-send` command only ever discovers one.

I definitely only have one wireless adaptor:  `ifconfig -a` lists: enp0s25, lo, sit0 and wlp3s0.

What does the `nmcli` command that the `dbus-send` command does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you have to run a rescan (method `RequestScan`) just before getting the list of SSIDs.